# C# Writing to a excel file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms

I have Data stored in DataTables and I'm trying to write that data into a .xlsx file, with multiple sheets. I don't how to go about it. Thanks

Comment: Please google, there are examples on this site and many others - what have you looked at

Comment: I think this answer will satisfy your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2603625/6241884

Answer (score 0):

Among many others, one way could be to use Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) to remote-control Excel. Another way would be to create an empty template XSLX file and fill that using OLEDB, for example described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8500/Reading-and-Writing-Excel-using-OLEDB). Or you could use one of the many libraries out there that do that.